# Php mysql query taking records from yesterday with a join check

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM (`videos`)
JOIN `ratings` ON `ratings`.`item_id` = `videos`.`id`
WHERE `videos`.`user_id` = 50
  AND `ratings`.`rated` = 'like'
  AND DATE(ratings.rating_date) = subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 1)
```

What is the problem with this query when I remove the last date check it gives me result otherwise the result is blank .Data is present in db.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: you will likely need to give us more detail such as what you are expecting, what you are getting.

Have you tried to see what the values of the 2 things in your where clause are? You can likely do it by doing a `select DATE(ratings.rating_date) as thing1, subdate(current_date, 1) as thing 2 from videos v, ratings r where v.id=r.item_id`

Comment: There are no ratings with yesterday's date? If that's not it, please make a sqlfiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I agree with Barmar, this would be much easier to solve with sqlfiddle and doesn't seem like it would be hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you did add field name `DATE(ratings.rating_date)` like this. please remove Date and try below code.

```
   SELECT *
    FROM (`videos`)
    JOIN `ratings` ON `ratings`.`item_id` = `videos`.`id`
    WHERE `videos`.`user_id` = 50
    AND `ratings`.`rated` = 'like'
    AND  ratings.rating_date = subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 1)
```

Also can try using if above code is not work.

```
`ratings.rating_date` = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```